# Using a Proxy with Google Analytics GA API Version 4 Python

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

Trying to use

```
HelloAnalytics.py
```

GA API script from:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py

Cannot get it to work, I have a Proxy here.  How to get it to work with a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little lite on description, but in general the below is one approach to manually set proxy at the global namespace level.

```
import os
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "https://login:password@ip_address:port"
```